# Error Checking file c#

Tags: c#

I have a program that opens a .txt file and stores it into an array. If the file contains anything other than one number per line than I get an error and the program crashes. I was wondering if there was a way to prevent this from happening and giving the user a message if their file is invalid.

```
public void Load_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.progressBar1.Value = 0; // Reset progress bar 
        List<int> list = new List<int>();

        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog(); // Initialize open file dialog 
        ofd.Filter = "TXT File|*.txt"; // Set acceptable files 
        ofd.Title = "Open File";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Open the selected file to read.
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName); // Read all lines in data file selected 
            dataArray = new int[lines.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.Length; ++i)
            {                  
                        dataArray[i] = int.Parse(lines[i]); // Add data to dataArray array 
                        Unsorted_Box.Text += lines[i] + ", "; // Add data to unsorted box 

            }// end for 
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're looking for a `catch` block or `int.TryParse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use int.TryParse():

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.Length; ++i)           
{                  
    if (!int.TryParse(lines[i],out dataArray[i]) // Add data to dataArray array 
    { 
       // do something about the invalid data - message / ignore  etc..
    }
    Unsorted_Box.Text += lines[i] + ", "; // Add data to unsorted box 

}// end for
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked. I just had to add break; to it so that it wouldn't keep looping through the for.

Comment: Do you know how I would error check this line: " var result2 = text.Split(" \r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)?.Select(num => double.Parse(num)).OrderBy(d => d).ToArray();"

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know how I would error check this line:
>   var result2 = text.Split(" \r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)?.Select(num => double.Parse(num)).OrderBy(d => d).ToArray();"

```
var result2 = text.Split(" \r\n".ToCharArray(), 
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)?.Select(num => 
         { 
            double result;  
            if (!double.TryParse(num, out result))
            { // error set result to value other than zero if you need to }
            return result;
         }).OrderBy(d => d).ToArray();"
```